# Default v-model value in vue-bootstrap-typeahead

Tags: vue.js

i am learning typeahead with vue js. And i want to ask how can i set the default value in food?

```
<vue-bootstrap-typeahead
    :data="list"
    v-model="food"
/>

data() {
    return {
        //Not work
        food: 'Apple',
        list: [],'
    }
}
```

FYI:https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-bootstrap-typeahead

Comment: Can you please explain how your current code doesn't work? What is it you want to see happen? How does this differ to what is actually happening?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a workaround from [github](https://github.com/alexurquhart/vue-bootstrap-typeahead/issues/22).  You can directly set the inputValue using a ref for the typeahead:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <vue-bootstrap-typeahead :data="list" v-model="food" ref="typeahead" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data: function() {
    return {
      food: "Apple",
      list: ["Aardvark", "Apple", "Beach", "Bear"]
    };
  },
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.typeahead.inputValue = "Apple";
  },
  methods: {}
};
</script>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/6xn4y5321k

Comment: i got it, thank you.
self.$refs.typeahead.inputValue = "Apple";